# scope of this inside arrow function vs regular

Tags: javascript

I'm going through a JavaScript problem with `this` and I don't understand something.

```js
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
    inner();
    function inner() {
        //A
        console.log("A", this.name); // this is too long so had to use this.name
    }
    //B
    console.log("B", this);

    //C
    ( () => console.log("C", this) )();
}

var myCat = new Cat('Markov');
```

I don't understand how it prints the right value for `()=>{}` arrow functions that's inside IFFE. Can someone enlighten me?

I thought the scope of `this` inside an IFFE with arrow would be `window` object :S

Comment: You don't have a traditional IIFE here. Your arrow function itself is immediately invoked. It certainly isn't *inside* an IIFE.

Comment: What do you mean .. it's still uses ( ..function) ();

Comment: `()` just forces it to expression context, it doesn't represent a function.